# Hartshorne exercise III. 12. 3

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm in trouble with the exercise problem iii.12.3 in Hartshorne's AG.

> Let $X_{1}$ be a rational normal curve in $\mathbb{P^4}$ ( = image of 4th veronese embedding of $\mathbb{P^1}$).
>
> $X_{0}$ be a rational quartic curve in $\mathbb{P^3}$ with parametrization $[t^4, t^3u, tu^3, u^4]$.
>
> Construct flat family $X$ using projection $\pi: \mathbb{P^4}\to \mathbb{P^3}$ parametrized by $\mathbb{A^1}$,with the given fibers $X_{1}$ and $X_{0}$ for $t=1$ and $t=0$.
>
> Let $\mathcal{I} \subset$ $\mathcal{O_{\mathbb{P^4}\times\mathbb{A^1}}}$ be a total idael sheaf of $X$.
>
> Show that the functions $h^0(t,\mathcal I_{t})$ and $h^1(t,\mathcal{I}_{t})$ are jump at $t=0$.

Still, my calculation doesn't lead to such answer. Rather, it seems to be that they are constant functions. I think such result is more acceptable because all fibers of $X$ are just $\mathbb{P^1}$.

What's wrong with me? I'll appriciate any comments.

Comment: Also posted at MathOverflow http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90260/trouble-with-semicontinuity